# conversion of dash in column name

Tags: peewee

I have to work with a database containing columns with a dash in their name, as for example **a-name**. When converting the table with peewee, it converts it to an illegal character, with python complaining about a misplaced operator.

For a table with 2 columns, **id** and **a-name**, the result would be

```py
from peewee import *

database = MySQLDatabase('databasename', **{'password': 'pwd', 'host': 'ip', 'user': 'username'})

class BaseModel(Model):
    class Meta:
        database = database

class ATable(BaseModel):
    id = PrimaryKeyField()
    a-name = CharField()

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'aTable'
```

I found a temporary workaround by changing the dash to an underscore and using the optional parameter **db_column**, like

```py
a_name = CharField(db_column='a-name')
```

Is there another possibility for this issue as I do not want to do manual changes everytime I download the models from the database server?

I should add that I have no control over the database server, I have merely an account with read-only permissions.

Greetings,

Luc

Answer (score 1):

`a_name = CharField(db_column='a-name')`

This is the correct way to solve the problem. Python does not allow dashes in identifiers, so if your column uses them then specify the column name explicitly and use a nice name for the column.

I suppose you could look into modifying the `playhouse.reflection.Introspector.make_column_name` method, as well.